# img onclick fire js function only second click

Tags: javascript, html

On `html` page I have several images with  `<img  onclick="povecaj();"` 
In fact, trying to make some kind of light-box.
First `img` click not work, second click fired function and any other `img` first click fired function. But after page loaded fist `img` click doesn't work...

function is next:

```
   function povecaj() {

        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            if ((screen.width > 801) || (screen.height > 801)) {
                init();
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        }

    }


    function init() {
        $(' .card-img img').click(function () {
            var thediv = document.getElementById('displaybox');
            var staza = $(this).attr('src')
            var sl = document.getElementById('image');
            thediv.style.display = "";
            sl.innerHTML = '<img  alt="2" id="imgID" src="' + staza + '"/>' + '<div class="alert-close" onclick = "zapri()" >X</div>'
            thediv.innerHTML = '<table style="width:100%; height:100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:central; width:100%; height:100%"></td></tr></tbody></table>';
            thediv.style.display = "block";
            sl.style = "block";

        });
    }
```

I'm working in `VS2012`, using Chrome inspect  too.. can't see errors..
searched, googled, can't find solution. Can somebody help?

Comment: Sorry, its my first post, as I see, some text was not recorded.

Comment: So, my problem is img click, on page loaded first click not fire js function, but next click works. and after that other images fire function on fist click.

Comment: function  `povecaj()` is never loaded

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Tnx for your comments

Comment: how do I add this peace of code - system reyect my text said txt is too long !?

Comment: tnx, we learn whole life :)

Comment: ttps://jsfiddle.net/xdn1szhr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images loading dynamically the DOM you must add a jquery event listener like this:

```
   function init() {
        $(class_of_parent_div).on('click', '.card-img img', function () {
            var thediv = document.getElementById('displaybox');
            var staza = $(this).attr('src')
            var sl = document.getElementById('image');
            thediv.style.display = "";
            sl.innerHTML = '<img  alt="2" id="imgID" src="' + staza + '"/>' + '<div class="alert-close" onclick = "zapri()" >X</div>'
            thediv.innerHTML = '<table style="width:100%; height:100%;"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:central; width:100%; height:100%"></td></tr></tbody></table>';
            thediv.style.display = "block";
            sl.style = "block";

        });
    }
```

And write the class of parent div `class_of_parent_div`

Comment: Try to write one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works. I added 3 div class name.

Comment: You need just one, for example `.card`  would be enough. By the way your code is so poor. Read the jquery documentation. You can write a less code with more functionality and less bugs. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again. I agree with you, I know that I have to learn a lot. I'm just a beginner in programming world but old enough (60) to be happy if something works when i write some code :)